# Vertical tabs in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to display tabs vertically. But I don't see the style at all. Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="vertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="vertical.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Tab A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Tab B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#c">Tab C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d">Tab D</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="a">Content of A</div>
    <div id="b">Content of B</div>
    <div id="c">Content of C</div>
    <div id="d">Content of D</div>
</div>
```

Below is the Javascript code. vertical.js

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $('#tabs')
    .tabs()
    .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
```

**CSS** vertical.css

```
.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical {
  padding: 0;
  width: 42em;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-widget-header {
  border: none;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.6em 1em;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 28em;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
}
```

What am I missing? What should be the order of the scripts at the top?
Can someone help please, TIA.

[[image]]

Comment: It is working perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/wf62m6mo/

Comment: Try this code [jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical)

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai When I try in the browser, tabs are being displayed just with bulletins. (I got the code only from fiddle)

Comment: @sahana: which means your css is not loaded. Check the network tab (in developer console) to see if the resource loaded properly or giving 404.

Comment: Console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" !

Comment: You might have jQuery conflict. Try using `jQuery` keyword instead of `$` or resolve conflict using `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: It means your jquery did not loaded properly. check the jquery path and file.

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai, path to jQuery source is absolute to jquery site and it is accessible.

Comment: yeah it is accessible !

Comment: check the path for vertical.js file

Comment: And also for `jquery-ui.css` & `vertical.css`. Are these files in same folder where your html file is placed?

Comment: Yes all are in the same folder !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the culprit. It was just the order of files I have mentioned at the top. 
Below is the order !

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="vertical.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="vertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks all for the serious inputs. It really helped me a lot.